# I can`t install Package "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" In VisualStudio 2019 Comunity Version 16.6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npm, visual-studio-2019

I want to install  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Package to Create AreaMVC and make views but The VisualStudio has this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmssq.png)

Comment: Have a look for this discussion: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5504

Answer (score 3):

Given the error Visual Studio gave you, it seems that you cannot connect to the nuget servers.

- Do you have a proxy enabled, or a firewall that is blocked nuget?
- Can you access nuget and download any other packages?
- If so, can you access the url in the error in a regular browser?
- Have you tried installing it through the Package Manager Console? (Using the command `Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 3.1.3`)

Comment: I tried with proxy and with out proxy but dose not work.
some packege exam "EntityFreamwork.SqlServer" has same error.
I tried to download with CLI but dose not work